# Android(Xamarin) Как получить данные с браслета через Bluetooth

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Моя цель получить данные(показатели пульса, давление) с фитнес браслета [Torntisc T1](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-Band/32809885498.html?af=10546_19&cv=89827&cn=41phbd7vvasud6o23bic4pk7omb96rn5&dp=v5_41phbd7vvasud6o23bic4pk7omb96rn5&af=10546_19&cv=89827&cn=41phbd7vvasud6o23bic4pk7omb96rn5&dp=v5_41phbd7vvasud6o23bic4pk7omb96rn5&afref=http%253A%252F%252Faway.vk.com%252Faway.ph&aff_platform=default&cpt=1540738220333&sk=ccfBY4yg&aff_trace_key=b7af637096ab419bacf3906c59c621a9-1540738220333-04174-ccfBY4yg&terminal_id=724836243f5247f4a5b23e873c75d5fe) с помощью своего приложения и самостоятельно обрабатывать данные с браслета. (родное приложение [H Band 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timaimee.hband&hl=en_US)).

Для реализации использую *Xamarin* и нашел плагин
  [Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/blob/master/README.md) для подключения к устройству и получению с него данных. Однако все получаемые характеристики имеют имя "*Unknow characteristi*c" и в значениях 0 байтов. Хотя при этом имеет 5 сервисов, в каждом из которых по 3 характеристики. Единственное в 1 сервисе название характеристик другие: "*Device Name*", "*Appearance*", "*Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters*". Однако значение(*value*) везде 0 байт. Как получить характеристики? Как получить данные о пульсе?

К браслету существует приложение *H Band 2.0*, который показывает достаточно большое количество настроек для браслета, возникает вопрос где всё это?

Наткнулся вот на такую [статью](https://habr.com/post/391109/) с схожей проблемой. Попытался [декомпилировать](https://yadi.sk/d/YSfrXiLj9H40oQ) родное приложение, чтобы найти как там работают с браслетом. Нашел классы отвечающие за связь по следующей директории: *sources\no\nordicsemi\android\dfu* . Вижу что сделано через *BluetoothGatt*. К сожалению я не специалист в java и android, незнаком с этой библиотекой. Методов или чего либо связанного с "pulse" или "heart" не обнаружил

Код ниже - получение характеристик через BLE для Xamarin

```
foreach (var TestService in Services)
            {
                var characteristics = await TestService.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                foreach (var Characteristic in characteristics)
                {
                    var properties = Characteristic.Properties;
                    var name = Characteristic.Name;
                    var serv = Characteristic.Service;
                    var value = Characteristic.Value;
                    var stringValue = value.ToString();
                    string result = "";
                    if (value.Length != 0)
                        result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value, 0, value.Length - 1);
                }
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не сможете найти данный файл так как этот файл он получил декомпилируя оригинальный продукт, вам нужно либо связаться с автором статьи или самому декомпилировать продукт, с которым он проводил манипуляции. Или поступить как он и взять оригинальное приложение для вашего браслета, декомпилировать и найти класс отвечающий за связь.

Comment: @Valeriy добавил ссылку на декомпилированный продукт. Нашел классы отвечающие за связь по следующей директории: *sources\no\nordicsemi\android\dfu* . Вижу что сделано через *BluetoothGatt*. К сожалению я не специалист в java и android, незнаком с этой библиотекой. Методов или чего либо связанного с "pulse" я не обнаружил, но зато большое количество магического парсинга характеристик: `parse(characteristic)`

Comment: Вы тут его и не найдёте, надо смотреть куда дальше передаётся значение "result", ведь именно в нём и хранится вся нужная информация. И ещё, было бы неплохо увидеть декомпилированый код всего приложения. Выгрузите его куда-нибудь.

Comment: @Valeriy я уже выложил декомпилированный код, https://yadi.sk/d/YSfrXiLj9H40oQ , ссылка есть и в вопросе